# Monospaced San Francisco Font in SKLabelNode

Tags: fonts, sprite-kit, tvos, apple-tv

I'm trying to use San Francisco **Monospaced** font (for time counter) in my `SpritKit` tvOS application. In there any way to do that since [SKLabelNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKLabelNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKLabelNode/fontName) only takes font name as an argument?

Making new font from monospaced `UIFontDescriptor` won't work because a name of this font doesn't contain information about a monospaced format.

Comment: Use a UILabel in your scene's GameViewController?